# Angular 4+ > In ts file, refer to file include in node_modules folder

Tags: angular, typescript

As mentioned in the question, i used in my Angular's project a package that need to refer to a file in the constructor (see below):

```js
constructor() {
    PDFJS.workerSrc = `./assets/js/pdf.worker.js`;
}
```

As you can see, till now, i managed to achieve this by putting my js file in my assets folder and get the path like this.
But actually it's not optimal.

**What am i trying to achieve is:** 
I want to refer to the file directly in node_modules folder while i'm in Dev, and when i'm in Prod, use Webpack to not compile this file (or something like this) and refer to it in my code !

**EDIT** 
This file is actually part of a package, so his location is directly in node_modules folder and what i am trying to achieve is to refer to this file actually.. The workaround i managed to do is to get this file and put it in my assets folder, but it's not good...

Do you have any advise for this ?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Add `pdf.worker.js` file in script:[] inside **angular-cli.json** (if you use Angular 4 otherwise angular.json). i hope you getting my point.

Comment: just try importing the packages directly

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should put these stuff into node_modules.
You can configure webpack what to compile in what case.
If you are in your `webpack.config` file:

```
module.exports = (env, argv) => {

  if (argv.mode === 'development') {

  }

  if (argv.mode === 'production') {
    //...
  }

  return config;
};
```

And in your running script you can configure the running mode for your webpack script.
something like webpack

```
webpack --progress --colors --config webpack.config.js --mode production
```

More about Webpack mode: https://webpack.js.org/concepts/mode/

Comment: i edit my questions, actually the file is already in the node_modules folder, and i'm trying to refer to this file in one of my ts file..^^